# How to get the token with django rest framework and ajax

Tags: python, ajax, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I want to build a rest api where users can authenticate with tokens. I have included `rest_framework.authtoken` in the installed apps list. Also added the required configuration in the settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'rest_framework.authtoken'
)

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
}
```

Defined a method to listen to `post_save` signal and create new token for the newly created user. Then I did migration. After creating new user I can see the token for that user.

Also if I do

```
http POST 0.0.0.0:80/api-token-auth/ username='user@gmail.com' password='secure123'
```

I get a this response back

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sat, 30 Jul 2016 12:05:30 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.3
Vary: Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

{
    "token": "4aecfb249265064c55300d782e4c7e66b8b77063"
}
```

So I suppose its working. But if I try to login with ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://test.com/api-token-auth/ username=' + email + ' password='+ password,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }.bind(this),
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.log(err);
    }.bind(this)
});
```

I get this error in the browser console:

> jquery-3.1.0.min.js:4 GET http://test.com/api-token-auth/%20username=user@gmail.com%20password=secure123?_=1469883569618 405 (Method Not Allowed)
>
> bundle.js:27453 Method Not Allowed

How do I get the token for authenticated user so that I can use it to post as authenticated user?

**update**

Also I am using [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) to deal with CORS related problem.

**update**

```
%20username=user@gmail.com%20password=secure123?_=1469885103431 405 xhr jquery-3.1.0.min.js:4   278 B   29 ms
```

**update: added response header**

[image]

Comment: Provide the details from your browser's network communication, in Chrome you find it in the debugger's network tab

Comment: @schacki Added the details. Please have a look.

Comment: %20 means space, in you ajax request replace ' username' with '?username' and ' password' to '&password'. Also I as remember this needs '&grant_type=password' parameter too. You can't have space (' ') in request url.

Answer (score 0):

By default the `type` or `method` value is set to 'GET' on jQuery.ajax() method. It lookls like the response you get, allows only 'POST', and 'OPTIONS'.

How about you try to set `type` or `method` value to 'POST' on your jQuery.ajax() method.

Comment: After I added the `method='POST'`, I am getting this error: `jquery-3.1.0.min.js:4 POST http://test.com/api-token-auth/%20username=user@gmail.com%20password=secure123 400 (Bad Request)`

Comment: can you past the response header?

Comment: Updated the question with the response header. Please have a look.

Comment: Did you change the settings for jQuery.ajax() method to pass the CSRF token in as POST data with every POST request? This is required for any "unsafe" HTTP method calls, such as PUT, PATCH, POST or DELETE requests.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cors issue, try with Chromium and start it with chromium-browser --disable-web-security to test it

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is because instead of send the data into the request payload, you are passing through URL, like a GET request.

The request you generate using `httpie` works because it correctly generate the request, as you can see:

**Request:**

```
http POST 0.0.0.0:80/api-token-auth/ username='user@gmail.com' password='secure123'
```

**Request (verbose mode):**

```
POST /api-token-auth/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 55
Content-Type: application/json
Host: 0.0.0.0:8000
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.9.3

{
    "password": "secure123",
    "username": "user@gmail.com"
}
```

Which is different from:

**Request:**

```
http POST "0.0.0.0:8000/api-token-auth/ username='user@gmail.com' password='secure123'"
```

**Request (verbose mode):**

```
POST /api-token-auth/%20username='user@gmail.com'%20password='secure123' HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Host: 0.0.0.0:8000
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.9.3
```

You can try this example I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23149151/jquery-and-django-rest-framework-bulk-send-list) of how send the data in the correct way using jQuery. (I din't test it.)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/articles/",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    sucess: function() { console.log("Success!"); },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain:false,
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a browser with an authenticated user you can get the token from a cookie.

`const csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');`

from: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/csrf/#ajax

Comment: note: this is a partial answer. It would be great if someone could provide reference on how a client that is not hosted in the browser can get a token.